# How can I approximate a function that is not derivable with derivable ones?

Tags: derivatives, interpolation, approximation-theory, spline

Suppose that I have a function whose graph has many angles (i.e. my function is not derivable). 
How can I approximate this function with derivable ones?

Thank you!

Comment: Intuitively you can take two points arbitrary close to the angle point of the function (and you can do this for any angle point) and interpolate between them with a polynomial.

Comment: Do you think of a function in particular ?

Comment: I don't see why you can't use Fourier series

Comment: My function is in $H^1(0,1)$

Comment: If it is continuous, you can uniformly approximate your function with polynomials, on any compact $[a,b]$ (Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, look for instance at the (slowly converging) constructive proof with Bernstein polynomials). Not quite sure if you can get the same guarantees on an interval $(a,b)$, even if allowing bigger classes than polynomials for your approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Chebfun system. It does a very good job of approximating any function by a polynomial (which the Weierstrass theorem tells us is possible, if the function is continous). In particular, [this page](http://www.chebfun.org/examples/approx/GreedyInterp.html) talks about approximating $|x|$, which is obviously not differentiable at $x=0$